# Android: Data list scrolling along with other components

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I'm trying to show a list of data in an android activity. Normally anyone would do that with a simple ListView which I have used many times before. But now I'm having an application with a fixed header and footer, with the middle part (the content) scrolling underneath both the header and the footer. In the middle section I would like to add other components both above and below the list of data, but the *entire* part must be scrollable. I tried adding components (like a button, textview etc) to a listview but the lay-out builder in Eclipse won't let me do that.

So I started using a ScrollView where you can easily add any component you like. But I am not allowed to add a ListView to a ScrollView, which I can understand as it would create a strange effect (as both are able to scroll).

Next I wanted to use a TableLayout to dynamically add TableRows, but on multiple websites it is said to be slow and 'not the way to do it'. I also couldn't find an elegant way to add the seperator between each item. With a ListView that would all be done very easily.

The following image probably explaines at best the effect I want: http://tinyurl.com/bvkec5d

The table with the 'Table Data' header can possibly have a lot of items and thus can become very large in length. What I *don't want* is that the table has a fixed size and the items are scrollable within that table. I actually want the table to grow in size and the ScrollView containing the table should therefore be growing as well. I also want the infobox above the table to scroll along (as with any other components which might be added later).

What is the best way to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple vertical LinearLayout (or a RelativeLayout) that contains your static header and footer, and use a ListView between them.  You can set header and footer views on the ListView to add the scrollable header and footer content.  For simplicity of example here's the LinearLayout way:

```
 <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" 
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_width="match_parent">
      <!--static header content... can be any kind of view-->
      <TextView 
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_weight="0"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
      <ListView 
               android:id="@+id/list"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="0dp"
               android:layout_weight="1"/>

      <!--static footer content... can be any kind of view-->
      <TextView 
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_weight="0"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

And in code, you can say:

```
ListView theList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

// example of creating header and footer views from inflation or by instantiation in code
View myHeaderView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.myHeaderLayout,theList,false);
View myFooterView = new TextView(this, some layout params);

theList.addHeaderView(myHeaderView); 
theList.addFooterView(myFooterView);
```

[ListView.addHeaderView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29) and ListView.addFooterView should enable you to add other static views (whose content could be updated dynamically) to the top or bottom of a ListView:

> ```
> public void addHeaderView (View v)
> ```
>
> Since: API Level 1 Add a fixed view to appear at the top of the list.
>   If addHeaderView is called more than once, the views will appear in
>   the order they were added. Views added using this call can take focus
>   if they want.
>
> NOTE: Call this before calling setAdapter. This is so ListView can
>   wrap the supplied cursor with one that will also account for header
>   and footer views.

Comment: I already have a vertical linearlayout as the root layout. The header and footer are already fixed and that's not the problem, I'm sorry if that's what you understood. My question is all about the middle section: That entire part must be scrollable, whatever the length of the data table. And I want all components within that middle section (which is a ScrollView) to scroll along.

Comment: I think you can do that by ListView.addHeaderView and ListView.addFooterView.  See the doc here:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html ...stupid link formatter... I can't actually link to the function. :(

Comment: Here http://tinyurl.com/7bdj7op you can find a new image. This image is what it is supposed to like like just after one has scrolled the middle section. As you can see, both the data table and the infobox above are scrolling along. Overal it's very common practice, but in this case I have a list of dates inside the ScrollView which can contain a random number of dates. I can't use a ListView, as that won't let me add other components (like the infobox). So my question is how to get this effect? I suggested TableLayout but some websites say it's 'not the way to do it' and slow.

Comment: I would suggest two things:  first, addHeaderView and addFooterView can be made to behave as you desire.  You can have more than one header or footer view and they will all scroll before + after the data in the list.  You would use, as a header view, all of your info box + the "Table Data" heading.  The list entries would be the row of dates, and the footer would be the button.  Does that make sense?  And if that can't be made to work, I think a TableLayout was largely designed for this case, especially if you won't have too much data in it.

Comment: In the case I'm using a header and footer view with the listview. Does that mean that the header and footer will scroll along with the list. So that when you start to scroll trough the list the header disappears and the footer only appears at the end of the list?

Comment: Yes.  addHeaderView and addFooterView views within the ListView will scroll along with the content. :)

Comment: Well I created a small test application with this header and footer attached to a listview and it is indeed exactly what I want! It's a bit complicated in my opinion, though. It's much easier to get this kind of result in iOS/Cocoa. Anyway.. Thank you very much!